# linux option to detect keyboard interrupt when making system call

Tags: linux, keyboardinterrupt

Usually when I run a program in terminal I am able to stop it with control C.
When I wrote a program which invoke an operating system command inside a while loop, the rest of the code executes so fast that there is no way to stop the program other than to kill the pid. The way I have been doing is adding a sleep for 1 second but it is not a good practice to fix it.

```
while(!phrasespotted){
     invoke an operating system command to arecord for 5 secs, during which control C can not stop the program 
     process the audio for phrase spotting 
     sleep(1); //during this I can stop the program in terminal 
}
```

What do I add to my code so that it can pick up the keyboard interrupt while making the system call, or even register it to stop it immediately after? 
Is threading the only option based on catching the signal? https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Comment: Can you please write a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? If you are running `system("arecord ...");` then this is **not** a system call. Having real code makes it easier to see what you mean.

Comment: corrected, now it is invoke an operating system command